# Postgres encoding trouble

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, encoding

I can not read my string properly. DB returns `=Љ дҐ "Ђи®вЁЄ"` instead of normal text. I can see this garbage text in server console, so I don't think there is a problem with page encoding. This is my configurations:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSourceMain" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> 
        <beans:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.101.158:5432/cafe" />
        <beans:property name="user" value="postgres" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="mypassword" />
        <beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="8" />
        <beans:property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
        <beans:property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMain" />
        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>               
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</beans:prop>             
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

    </beans:bean>
```

Also I've got this in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

My query that creates db:

```
CREATE DATABASE "cafe"
  WITH OWNER "postgres"
  ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The server console not displaying the text correctly might be a problem with the console's encoding. Did you debug your application and check the string that has been read from the db directly in the debugger? And did you check the value in the database?

Comment: I can see a normal string in my psql console.

Comment: Кафе "Ашотик"? It is imb866 encoded text converted to Windows1251. Very strange, maybe some old data?

Comment: Did you try with the `?charSet=UTF-8` jdbc URL parameter, instead of the `hibernate.connection.charSet` property?